# array with size to be determined during run time in c language?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, runtime, user-input

I want to make an array whose size is to be determined during run time i.e. user input.

I tried to do  it like this:

```
printf("enter the size of array \n");

scanf("%d",&n);

int a[n];
```

But this resulted in an error.

How do I set the size of an array like this?

Comment: What compiler are you using and what error is it showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using C99 (or newer) you need to allocate memory manually, e.g. using `calloc()`.

```
int *a = calloc(n, sizeof(int)); // allocate memory for n ints
// here you can use a[i] for any 0 <= i < n
free(a); // release the memory
```

If you do have a C99-compliant compiler, e.g. GCC with `--std=c99`, your code works fine:

```
> cat dynarray.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        printf("enter the size of array \n");
        int n, i;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = 1337;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
> gcc --std=c99 -o dynarray dynarray.c
> ./dynarray
enter the size of array
2
1337 1337
```

Comment: Why if OP has a c99 compliant compiler?

Comment: "Unless you are using C99". C11 hasn't removed variable length arrays.

Comment: @CharlesBailey agree with the comment, but C11 also made them optional

Comment: @ThiefMaster also nitpicking, why `calloc` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: It automatically zeroes the allocated memory.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Don't forget that `calloc` is slower comparing to  `malloc` because of the overhead of the zeroing.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı: Why are you directing that at me?

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı: That's most likely negligible. Unless you initialize every element right after allocating the memory you better zero the memory anyway.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `stdio.h`, declare `n` and put your code in a function. Other than that what you've done should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int n;
        printf("enter the size of array \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n];
}
```

Comment: And switch your compiler to C99 mode

Comment: Please leave a reason if downvoting. Thanks.